# Changing input format and database issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm tasked with fixing a job information page at work. When someone clicks "edit job" to edit a job, a form of all the database titles and values is listed and they can click on an input box and change it and update. Basic stuff.

Now, in the input box for "Payment terms:" the percentages are written exactly like this, "40/40/20" and so in the database under payment they're listed as 40/40/20.

So the label + input box looks like this, Payment terms: [40/40/20].

```
<p><label for='payment'>Payment Terms</label><input name='payment'
id='payment' value='<?php if(isset($data2['payment'])) echo 
$data2['payment']; ?>' /></p>
```

I want to change this to 4 drop down boxes where they can pick the percentages, for instance

```
Payment terms: [40]
               [40]
               [20]
               [empty]
```

There is a TON of jobs with their own payment terms in the db and I think I may have to add 4 columns to the db instead of just 1 column named payment and values listed as %/%/%/%.

Obviously that doesn't seem like a good solution as it would take forever to fix all the jobs and enter their data for each term into the new columns.

What should I do ?

Comment: I don't think you should dismiss the idea of fixing the table by adding 4 new fields that have each percentage and then writing a script that goes through the existing database and parses the single existing field into the new field. Explode and split could be used. The issue is how many other scripts currently parse this db field and is it difficult to change those?

Comment: I'm new to this system and job (first job out of college) but from what I've seen only 1 script parses the data from that field. I don't want to dabble with the db too much just yet so I'll go the explode route which will provide a solution for now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode` to split the string from your database. Then you can make 4 `<select>` boxes:

```
<?php
$selects = 4;
if (isset($data2['payment'])) {
  $percentages = explode("/", $data2['payment']);
  // Make sure that the array is long enough by adding zeroes to the end
  while (count($percentages) < $selects) $percentages[] = 0;
}
else {
  $percentages = array_fill(0, $selects, 0);
}

$options = range(10, 100, 10);

for ($i = 0; $i < $selects; ++$i) { ?>
<select>
  <option></option>
  <?php foreach ($options as $o) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"
      <?php if ($o == $percentages[$i]) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>
        <?php echo $o; ?>
    </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

I put the blank option first as it will be selected by default that way.

Comment: Awesome, looks great! Now I'm trying to get a 4th select box in there but it keeps throwing an error, Undefined offset: 3. 

What could be causing this error? I tried everything but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. The option boxes are percentages from 10% to 100%. I've fixed that anyway. Everything else looks good its just that 4th option box is throwing the error.

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho I've edited the code to produce 4 select boxes, with the 10-100% range. One possible problem would be when the string isn't long enough so the `$percentages` array wouldn't have a 4th element. I've added a fix for that.

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho sorry, the code was garbled before, it's fixed now.

Comment: I will come back and do that as soon as I reach 15 rep haha